# Angular 4 ng serve return no value in database when doing restAPI

Tags: angular, api

I try to make a restAPI based on this tutorial https://www.codeofaninja.com/2016/12/angular-crud-tutorial.html. But when i reached step 6.9 the output is blank. The code was compiled fine and no error was returned. i try to run only localhost/api/product/read.php in my browser and its return database data in JSON format on the chrome. I am still new and beginner to angular 4. Also hope to hear any comment about restAPI and Angular 2/4 also will be really helpful to me.

[Angular Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ipUb.png)

This is an example of my product.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Product } from './product';

@Injectable()

// Service for products data.
export class ProductService {

    // We need Http to talk to a remote server.
    constructor(private _http : Http){ }

    // Get list of products from remote server.
    readProducts(): Observable<Product[]>{
        return this._http
            .get("http://localhost/api/product/read.php")
            .map(res => res.json());
    }

}
```

This is my example of read-products.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from '../product.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Product } from '../product';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-read-products',
    templateUrl: './read-products.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./read-products.component.css'],
    providers: [ProductService]
})

export class ReadProductsComponent implements OnInit {

    // store list of products
    products: Product[];

    // initialize productService to retrieve list products in the ngOnInit()
    constructor(private productService: ProductService){}

    // methods that we will use later
    createProduct(){}
    readOneProduct(id){}
    updateProduct(id){}
    deleteProduct(id){}

    // Read products from API.
    ngOnInit(){
        this.productService.readProducts()
            .subscribe(products =>this.products=products['records']);
    }
}
```

This is an example of read-products.component.html

```
<div class="row m-b-18px">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- button to create new product -->
        <a (click)="createProduct()" class='btn btn-primary pull-right'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span> Create Product
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

        <!-- HTML table for our list of product records -->
        <table class='table table-hover table-responsive table-bordered'>

            <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>

            <!-- Use *ngFor directive to loop throught our list of products. -->
            <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.price}}</td>
                <td>{{product.description}}</td>
                <td>{{product.category_name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <!-- read one product button -->
                    <a (click)="readOneProduct(product.id)" class='btn btn-primary m-r-5px'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></span> Read
                    </a>

                    <!-- edit product button -->
                    <a (click)="updateProduct(product.id)" class='btn btn-info m-r-5px'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span> Edit
                    </a>

                    <!-- delete product button -->
                    <a (click)="deleteProduct(product.id)" class='btn btn-danger m-r-5px'>
                        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Delete
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post some code, how are you calling that api ? is there any response when logging in and how are you populating the template

Comment: Check your console. It's likely a runtime error (pre-closed tag, missing variable, etc).

Comment: post your console errors and have you enabled cors on you rest API

Comment: @sky can you just console log in ngonint inside of the subscribe to check if data is coming fine and also check the browsers console its seems fine to me

Comment: @PraneethReddy and Rahul Singh, thanks for your help. When i check on the console, its written there no providers for Http module. Now i solved it, really its a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, when i checked on the console. Its return no provider for http and i add on HttpModule and its solved.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {  HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReadProductsComponent } from './products/read-products/read-products.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ReadProductsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule, HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```